# Differences in calling `system()` from within RStudio or via Rscript?

Tags: r, bash, rstudio

I am trying to run external tools from the [MEME suite](http://meme.nbcr.net), one of this tool (jaspar2meme) producing a text file that is then use as an input of a second tool (fimo). Here is my code :

```
#!usr/bin/Rscript

com1 <- "meme/bin/jaspar2meme"
arg1 <- "-bundle jaspar_plant_2014.pfm"
message("jaspar2meme command: ", com1, arg1)
system2(command = com1, args = arg1, stdout =  "motif.fimo", wait = T)

com2 <- paste0("meme/bin/fimo")
arg2 <- paste0("--text --oc . --verbosity 1 --thresh 1.0E-4 --bgfile bg.fimo motif.fimo Genes_up_h16.ame")
message("FIMO command: ", com2, arg2)
system2(command = com2, args = arg2, stdout = "fimoresult.txt", wait = T)
```

When I run this code from within RStudio (via `source`), it works perfectly: the file `motif.fimo` is produced by `jaspar2meme` and use by `fimo` to produce the resulting file `fimoresult.txt`.

When I run the same script via `Rscript` from the shell (bash), the `motif.fimo` is also produced as expected but is not found by `fimo`and the `fimoresult.txt` remains empty.

What I tried so far is to use either `system()` or `system2()`, using the `wait=T` option or not, specifying the full path to `motif.fimo` but without success.

Comment: I believe `methods` isn't loaded in RScript, so you might need to load that, if some of the code is based on this?

Comment: Just by calling `library("methods")` ? It doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it... The `locale` variables were different in RStudio and Rscript. The `motif.fimo` file produced by `jaspar2meme` looked the same in both cases but was apparently not. By changing the first call to `system2()` by :

```
system2(command = com1, args = arg1, stdout =  "motif.fimo", wait = T, env = c("LC_NUMERIC=C"))
```

solve my problem.